# Xcode: UIImageView Position(Moving With NSTimer) Resets After Different UIImage Image Changes

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, xcode6, nstimer, reset

For some strange reason the `UIImageView` that moves down through `NSTimer` seems to reset and continue moving every time I click on the `IBAction` that changes the different `UIImageView` image.

Here is the code:

**In my .h**

```
@interface Game : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;


    NSTimer *myTimer;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *differentImage1;
```

**In my .m**

```
 -(IBAction)start{

        myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(Movement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }
    -(void)Movement{

        image1.center = CGPointMake(image1.center.x, image1.center.y + 7);

    }

    -(IBAction)changeDifferentImage{

        _different1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];

    }

    -(IBAction)changeDifferentImage2{

        _different1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];

    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify?  Also, be careful with NSTimer -- you need to make sure you invalidate and nil it out if you are going to re-use it, otherwise you can end up with multiple timers.

Comment: @olynoise While image1 is moving, and the button is clicked to change different1 image the image1 resets to the position it started and continues moving. It resets like this every time the image for different1 is changed through the two buttons (changeDifferentImage and changeDifferentImage2). Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell from your code the relationship between image1 (is that a view?) and _different1.  Could you add more code?

Comment: @olynoise Yes, just give me a minute.

Comment: @olynoise I've updated the question. It's a short code. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm.  I still can't tell from your code.  There might be a bug in your IB file.

Comment: @olynoise,  try it yourself. Does it happen to you?